# Is it possible to read table from database & write to another table in same code at python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I want write python code which read data from one table & do some operation & write the output along with some more columns from previous table in same database at same code.
Here is description::
I have table (name= table-1) from where I am reading data. Doing some operation & getting value in some variable. I want store that value in table-2 in same database in a same code.
I have use two cursor (curr-1 for table1 to read & doing some operation)&(curr-2 for table2 to insert value)
I am inserting the value (using curr-2) where I am getting value in the code.

Here some sample code which I would like to execute:

```
connection_1= sqlite3.connect('/home/Documents/attendance_report/data.db')
cur_1 = connection_1.cursor()
connection_2 = sqlite3.connect('/home/Documents/attendance_report/data.db')
cur_2 = connection_2.cursor()
cur_2.execute('select * from table-1')
count=1
for row in cur_2:
    count+=1
    ##doing some operation in the variable name(xyz)
    new_row = [col1_4m_table_1,col2_4m_table_1,xyz]
    cur_1.execute('''insert into total_time values(?,?,?)''', new_row)
```

And also that variable xyz is in timedelta format,which output should display like 09:23:54 format.it's not working if declare as (time) format

code has not syntax & logical error.
Deeply thanks & welcome for your feedback. If need some clearance please fell free to ask

Comment: */reading first line..* Wait, we're not here to please you..

Comment: Thank you for getting that meaning. For your kind information, Usually this please means kindly.......

Comment: @user2956480 "code has not syntax & logical error" - so what's the problem?

Comment: Why are you using two different connections?

Comment: @CL BECAUSE CUR_1 FOR DOING SOME OPERATION FROM TABLE-1 & CUR_2 FOR WRITING VARIABLE FOR ANOTHER TABLE

Comment: @CL I HAVE TRIED TO USE ONE CURSOR,BUT DID NOT WORK

Comment: @Mureinik ITS NOT WRITE ANYTHING. BUT IF I PRINT THE VARIABLE IN GUI IT GIVES WRITE O/P

Comment: I said "connections", not "cursors".

Comment: @user2956480 using all capitals is CONSIDERED SHOUTING and therefore rude... Please [edit] your question to include these things you've tried so others' can see all this information in one place (and not all in capitals!):)

Comment: @CL as per my knowledge connection are use to refer cursor()..so if I want to do two things then I have use two connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple connections would interfere with each other if they could read and write at the same time.

To execute multiple SQL statements, use two cursors from the same connection.